# 0 records when importing a JSON file in mysql WorkBench

Tags: mysql, json, database, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import a .json into a database using MySQL workbench, but the "Table data import wizard" always end up with 0 records.

here's the first line of my .json:

```
{
 "Title":"Fort de Villiers",
 "Keywords":"Histoire",
 "Descripion":"Le fort de Villiers est un ancien fort du système défensif de Paris, situé sur la commune de Noisy-le-Grand, dans le département français de Seine-Saint-Denis. Construit à la fin du XIXᵉ siècle, il faisait partie du système Séré de Rivières, destiné a établir un rideau défensif autour de Paris.",
 "Images":["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/J-7ut85_OfCJn33_EZcooBkGyjxGBXt5CifUJ_bGzHaZUHlT4XVYwNaIKpZ4hScn3ICcUMI12RZ4xzTxUGmN1LCK694hynag4zh68dLypDwQ_Gy9NwCIFweGTjkh3Wft4IMr0No1tFWbTQ6oBnmLgRaomsWzvoJrTa8=w296-h202-n-k-no","https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNs2wi72SiKVlLr1WHIPfAaATrXOfhswYWEIaOw=w296-h202-n-k-no","https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMIY16VgeazmwQAP7PB5biaq5p-9uE3OZ-zVYZB=w296-h202-n-k-no"],
 "Lattitude":"48.833573",
 "Longitude":"2.5463771",
 "Map_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/place/Fort+de+Villiers/@48.833573,2.5463771,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47e60e0d72beac57:0xd4b8549d2165eef7!8m2!3d48.8335733!4d2.5551319"
}
```

when i try to import it, i got those fields proposed:

```
Title : Text
Description : Text
Longitude : Double
Images : json
Map_url : Text
Keywords : Text
Lattitude : Double
```

With some research i found out that it may be that the "text" columns countains characters that doesn't fill the requiring format, but i didn't manage to get the right format.

Do i need to modify my .json to get a correct utf8 format?

I'm actually using mysql 8.

Comment: I'm trying to import a json file I literally just exported from another mysql instance, and I get the same "0 records" result on import :-(

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: nope, i switched to mongodb, way better